# Question on how to prove sup(A) = sup(B) = sup(C)

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about a calculus question regarding the Supremum of a set

Here is said question:

Let there be sets $A,B,C$. Neither one is empty and they are all upper bound. 
Given:

$\forall a\in A\quad \exists b\in B\quad :a\leq b$

$\forall b\in B\quad \exists c\in C\quad :b\leq c$

$\forall c\in C\quad \exists a\in A\quad :c\leq a$

Prove or Disprove that:
$\sup(A) = \sup(B) = \sup(C)$

Now intuitively I understand that this can actually happen. Its the proving it that I'm having difficulty with.

My plan was to prove the first couple (a & b) and create some kind of Lemma out of it, and then to use said Lemma to prove the two other couples.
I'm pretty certain that I need to use $\varepsilon$ somewhere in my proof but I'm getting stuck and having a difficulty understanding how I would prove said equation.

Any hints or ideas on how I can proceed?

Comment: Using your first property, prove $\sup(A)\leq\sup(B)$. Can you proceed from there?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
Prove
$$\sup A \le \sup B \le \sup C \le \sup A$$

Comment: OK proving this is not that difficult, its already written down as the start of my proof, but I can't seem to understand how this helps me in proving that they are all equal

Comment: Never mind, I see it now. Thanks! Really appreciate it

Comment: Any questions remaining? If not so, please mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the condition that $$\forall a\in A\:\exists b\in B:a\le b.$$ From this, we can see that $\forall a\in A,$ we have $a\le\sup(B)$, from which it follows that $\sup(A)\leq\sup(B).$ (Why?)

Similar arguments will show from the other two conditions that $\sup(B)\le\sup(C),$ and that $\sup(C)\le\sup(A).$ Hence, we're done.

Comment: OK I can Prove that $sup(A)\leq sup(B)$ pretty easily using the fact that every a is smaller than b hence their sup(A) must also be smaller than sup(B). But how does that help me about proving that they are equal?

Comment: Be careful with your reasoning. Saying "every $a$ is smaller than $b$" is incorrect. In fact, it turns out that for every $b\in B,$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $b\le a$. Rather, since $\forall a\in A\:\exists b\in B:a\le b,$ and since $\forall b\in B,\:b\le\sup(B),$ then $\forall a\in A,\:a\le\sup(B)$.

Comment: Since $\sup(A)\le\sup(B)\le\sup(C)\le\sup(A),$ then for example, $\sup(A)\le\sup(B)\le\sup(A),$ and so $\sup(A)=\sup(B).$ Likewise, we can see that $\sup(A)=\sup(C)$, and so they are all equal. More generally, if we have a finite collection of real numbers $a_1,...,a_n$ such that $a_1\le\cdots\le a_n\le a_1,$ then all of the $a_k$ are equal.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you, I see the idea for the proof. Yeah the wording I used in my comment was not accurate, I rushed the comment a bit :)

Comment: You are welcome. You see that there will be no need for an $\varepsilon$ in this argument, yes? We can simply note that since $\forall a\in A,\:a\le\sup(B)$, then $\sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A,$ but $\sup(A)$ is the *least* upper bound of $A$, and so $\sup(A)\le\sup(B)$.

Comment: Yeah, initially I tried proving it using the inequalities and finding the relationships between the different supremums, but got confused and stuck. A teaching assistant in my University hinted that it can be proven rather nicely with ε which is why I thought that the proof needed to be done that way. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

From the first and second conditions you get $\sup(A)\leq \sup(B)\leq \sup(C)$. From the third condition you get $\sup(C)\leq \sup(A)$. By transitivity of $\leq$ you get $\sup(A)=\sup(B)=\sup(C)$.

Comment: Oh I see it now...very nice. Thanks